# Which media player should I use for tv series?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-player

I want to watch tv series I have as video files on my computer (i.e. ripped from dvds I own), whilst keeping track of which episode I've already seen.

I'm perfectly comfortable with using nautilus for browsing my directory structure but would also accept some database driven player.

What are my options here? I've tried Banshee and XMBC/Boxee. While Banshee didn't look nice at all, XBMC and Boxee nicely scanned my drive, put cover art in its overview screen etc. But I feel it's not really useful in my situation where I sit in front of my computer doing other things and want to watch movies/series on my second screen

Answer (score 1):

You would be really happy with [Miro](http://getmiro.com) [image: Install Miro].

Here a screenshot to show the feature you are looking for. It also shows if you have not finished watching a video, and allows you to resume where you stopped the video.

[image: Miro]

Answer (score 0):

I use boxee and xbmc on my 2nd display all the time.  Of course your second display could be a huge tv if you wanted.  Theres also VLC and mplayer, almost any of the video players can play the tv shows.  Theres also moovidia.  Have fun.